# jQuery onclick not functioning properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I have this set so that it would send a message whenever i click on a  in the  of yep-table . it's not working for some reason. is there anything wrong with this?

heres the jquery

```
$("yep-table tbody").on("click", "tr", function(e) {
    console.log("clicked");
});
```

heres the html

```
<table class="table" id="yep-table">
                      <thead>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Cuisine</th>
                        <th>Address</th>
                        <th>Average Score</th>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                          
                      </tbody>
                  </table>
```

the 's are loaded in using another jquery function but it doesn't matter because even if i set it to click on the , it still doesnt work

Comment: I'm not the best at jQuery but I'm pretty sure it's like `$("#yep-table tbody).click(function() { console.log('clicked')}`

Comment: @YT_Xaos Yeah i was missing the #, tyvm